# How to fix long delay after loading lazily loaded chunk in Angular

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

I have divided the Angular project in multiple modules. Initially, main module gets loaded with login page. Once user logs in, second module gets loaded.

Now, once user clicks on login button, screen is getting halted in the same page for 13-14 secs after that it is moving to next page.

Chuck is hardly taking time to load in network.

What should I do to avoid this delay after clicking login.

Note: This only happens once.If user logout and login again, it won't take time.

I thought my second bundle is taking time to complile but project was taking less time before dividing into modules.